# html5 geolocations with jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to implement html5 geolocations with jquery mobile.

this is the original code I have that works perfect in an html document but just isn't working with jquery mobile.

```
    <script>
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.842535, lng: -87.697091},
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://dawebmaster.com/apps/dawebmastersMAP.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('You\'re Here.');
    map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
    } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    }

    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Okay so this code below works with jquery mobile exactly how I want it too but everytime i trying adding the htmll5 geolocation it doesnt work.

```
    <script>
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#page2',function(e,data){   

        $('#content').height(getRealContentHeight());

       // This is the minimum zoom level that we'll allow
       var minZoomLevel = 12;

       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: {lat: 41.842535, lng: -87.697091},
          disableDefaultUI: true
       });
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://dawebmaster.com/apps/dawebmastersMAP.kml',
        suppressInfoWindows: false,
        map: map,
        preserveViewport: true
       });

       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
    });
    function getRealContentHeight() {
        var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
        var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
        var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
        var viewport_height = $(window).height();

        var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
        if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
            content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
        } 
        return content_height;
       }
      </script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

I am trying to add the html5 geo location code to the second one. I added it before the last function and after it but its not working.

I've tried adding it in different place in the second code but nothing is working...

Here is the full code I am trying to add... I just need someone to point me in the right direction. This is frustrating.....

```
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

   infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
   infoWindow.setContent('You\'re Here.');
   map.setCenter(pos);
   }, function() {
   handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
   });
   } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
   }
   }

   function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
   infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
   infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
   }
```

Comment: I got it fixed.... in the html5 geolocation  where it says "browser doesn't support geolocation" after the following line it had two barracks and it only needed one haha....

Comment: May be a good idea to set an answer for others that run across this, and then mark the answer.